# When sending e-mail to "self" using gmail API, how do you determine when/if message will arrive?

Tags: gmail, gmail-api

I'm using google's latest python libraries to send/receive e-mails to self (i.e., to and from fields are the same as the user account being used to send) to collect network performance metrics.

When I send a message, a 'msgId' is created which can be used to track the message that was sent. I can then subsequently delete (or trash)  that 'msgId'.  However, from time to time, AFTER I delete the msgId, the same message seems to "arrive" but is given a different msgId. If I wait sufficiently long enough period (10-15seconds) between sending and deleting, I only ever see the same msgId as returned by the user.message.create(), the delete is successful and only ever see the single msgId.

I believe there may be some kind of race condition whereby when sending within GMAIL (or perhaps only when sending to self), it uses the same message instance for both the sent and received message...and if the sent message is deleted before it is actually received, a new msgId is created for the received msg.

**Question:** Is there a way to determine whether a sent message (to self) has been received and can be deleted without risk of the message being received later and a new msgId generated?

I've tried moving the sent message to TRASH and then poll the message to receive the label for 'INBOX' without avail.

Comment: please edit your question include your code and describe any issues you are having with your current solution.

Comment: So your goal is to collect network performance metrics but you are using Google servers to do so. Surely then your "network" is not going to be very reliably the same, since for every request, the server in use may be a different server. This is a very unconventional way to get performance metrics. It seems like you are looking for some parameter that will deliver your message after an exact measure of time after its sent, is that correct?